# How to resolve Reporter "spec" does not exists in karma?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a project that used `generator-angular` version `0.3.0` and I am trying to add a `spec` reporter to its karma tests, but I keep getting `Reporter "spec" does not exists in karma`

After reading some resources, I did the following steps

- ran the command `npm install karma-spec-reporter --save-dev`
- I modified the karma configuration file (added 'spec')

  `reporters = ['progress','dots','junit','spec'];`
- I ran `grunt` (which in turn runs `karma` ) and got the error

How can I get the spec reporter to work in my environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is running into this issue, one solution to this problem is to upgrade karma. 
I don't know if there's a solution to the version I was using (I have no idea which version that was, sorry) but once I upgraded the version, it worked fine.

One of the markers to make sure karma was upgraded is the need for the configuration file to be of the following format

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
         //... the usual configuration converted from a=b to a:b
         reporters : ['spec'],// -- now this works well.. finally :) 
         //... some more configuration

    });
}
```

The upgrade went pretty smoothly. no great surprises. I recommend upgrading.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into the same issue.

Gets fixed by loading the plugin, but the user guides at NPM and github for the some of Karma plugins are not mentioning it anywhere.

```
       plugins: ['karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-coverage', 'karma-browserify', 'karma-spec-reporter'],

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['coverage', 'progress', 'spec'],
```

Update: there is a new version of this plugin that does tell you to load it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-spec-reporter-2

Answer (score 2):

Ran in to the same today and, what worked for me was installing karma-spec-reporter globally.

I had already worked on the project on one PC and had done `--save-dev` when installed the reporter on that machine. Once I pulled the project to the other machine I assumed doing `npm install` would have just worked. It didn't and I was getting the same error. Doing `npm i karma-spec-runner --save-dev` didn't work either (even after restarting the shell) and then I tried `npm i -g karma-spec-runner` and that worked.